# Navigation Single click not working on desktop

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, navigation

Does anyone happen to know the cause of this navigation requiring Double Click on desktop?

I've been brought in to work with a custom built theme and it seems their mobile navigation may be disrupting the desktop navigation.

Website (Short URL to avoid indexing):
(URL REMOVED)

If you attempt to view any page within the navigation it requires double clicking. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

(I suspect it's related to the Mobile version of the navigation but am uncertain.)

Comment: Works fine for me on Firefox. With the navigation do you mean the top menu with ACT Presents, Buy Tickets, etc? Maybe try a full cache clear or try a diff browser

Comment: I'm not experiencing any double clicking requirements in Chrome.

Comment: Quite odd. @Brett yes I do mean that area though it doesn't seem to work with Chrome or Internet Explorer. (Chrome: Version 62.0.3202.89, IE: Version 11.674.15063.0) I have tried clearing the browser cache though sadly it doesn't resolve the issue. I've also seen on multiple devices so finding it odd that it works for you both.

Comment: @Andrew do you happen to use a previous version of Chrome? I seem to notice each link only work if clicked twice in Chrome?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 61.0.3163.100 @MattS   just upgraded to the latest version 62.0.3202.89 and it also works.  Try disabling any browser plugins that you might have installed...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue to be specific to my device, I'll be marking this as resolved. Thanks tons to Brett & Andrew for your time helping me determine this.